# How to control the width of radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

I have a RadGrid but it is spanning the width across the page, how can I control it and set a width and mae contents in the cells wrap if they need to?. I cant find anything that is helping me. I tried MasterTableView-TableLayout="fix" but then anything in the cells gets cut off. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
 <RadGrid:CustomRadGrid ID="DetailsGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
 ShowFooter="True" OnNeedDataSource="DetailsGrid_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="DetailsGrid_ItemDataBound"
OnItemCreated="DetailsGrid_ItemCreated" 
OnItemCommand="DetailsGrid_ItemCommand"
GridLines="None" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" 
AllowPaging="True" 
AllowSorting="True"
AllowMultiRowSelection="true">
```

**THIS IS A CUSTOM GRID**

Comment: what happened when you put it in the RadGrid tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Width` attribute in the main `RadGrid` tag. Content in cells will automatically wrap. You may have to set the width on individual columns as well to get the appropriate look. The auto column width doesn't always wrap where you want it to.

Comment: I did exactly that on my grid and it worked. Maybe OP is using a custom grid?

Comment: Nothing happens when i do this

Comment: Yes it is a custom Grid - existing not created by me

Comment: In that case, unfortunately you'll have to look at the source code for the grid to see what it's doing to the width, and if there is any way to set it. You may need to modify the custom grid control class to allow a width to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

For RadGrid width you just need to set width of the grid.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="ViewLogsGrid" FilterType="Combined"
            runat="server"
            AllowFilteringByColumn="true"                
            PageSize="50"
            ShowStatusBar="true"
            AllowPaging="True"
            AllowSorting="True"

            Width="1250px"

            AllowFiltering="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            GridLines="None"
            CellSpacing="0">

    </telerik:RadGrid>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Columns inside the grid will adjust as needed but if you need to fix a column width do the following (Telerik doesn't recommend it);

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="ViewLogsGrid" ... ... >

   <MasterTableView TableLayout="Fixed">
      <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments"    UniqueName="Comments">

           <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />

        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      </Columns>
   </MasterTableView>

</telerik:RadGrid>
```